# Why is my $('form :input').change() not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am practising JavaScript, and I am trying to make a button clickable when if any radio-button in the form is clicked. But my $('form:input').change() event is never triggered. 
Here is HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>blah</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$('form :input').change(function () {
    alert("changed");
    if($("input[type=radio]:checked").length === 0){
        $('#voteButton').prop('disabled', true);
    }else{
        $('#voteButton').prop('disabled', false);
    }
})
$(document).ready(function () {
        if($("input[type=radio]:checked").length === 0){
            $('#voteButton').prop('disabled', true);
        }
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>    
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice1" value="1">
    <label for="choice1">Just hacking again</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice2" value="2">
    <label for="choice2">Nothing</label><br>
    <input type="submit" value="vote" name="voteButton" id="voteButton">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The thing is, I made a js fiddle ( https://jsfiddle.net/3wLmxmu6/4/ ) and it's working on the fiddle. But on my computer though, it is not. I have been beating my head over this for the past 2 hours and couldn't find any reason.
My browser's console shows no error/warning either, both in chrome and firefox. 
Can anyone tell me what is happening here and how do I resolve it? Thank you very much.

Comment: `$('form :input')...` inside document-ready handler

Comment: Incoming answers instead of voting to close as a typo in 3... 2.. 1...

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, Are you still counting?

Comment: It seems to me that input elements do not exist when you're trying tio subscribe for events ( when script runs )

Comment: Um, I put the $('form:input') inside the documenty-ready handler, and it is still not working.
Why am I getting downvotes?

Comment: @Satpal I ran out of fingers

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting downvotes is becaouse your question lacks reseach.

How jquery change works can be found [here](https://api.jquery.com/change/)

As for your question:

```
 <form>    
        <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice1" value="1">
        <label for="choice1">Radio 1</label><br>
        <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice2" value="2">
        <label for="choice2">Radio 2</label><br>
        <input type="submit" value="vote" name="voteButton" id="voteButton" disabled = 'true'>
    </form>
```

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('form :input').change(function () {
            alert("changed");
            if($("input[type=radio]:checked").length === 0){
                $('#voteButton').prop('disabled', true);
            }else{
                $('#voteButton').prop('disabled', false);
            }
        })
    });
```

Updated your fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/3wLmxmu6/5/)